# Is this a space filling curve for a torus?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $\Lambda:= \{m +ni : m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ be a complex lattice, so that our fundamental period parallelogram (fpp) is just the unit square. Define two complex numbers to be equivalent if $z_1 - z_2 \in \Lambda$.

If a point $z=x+yi \in \mathbb{C}$ has finite order $n$ in $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ (assuming $x \not=0$), then the line intersecting the origin (which is also the bottom left corner of the fpp) with slope $\frac{y}{x}$ goes from the bottom to the top (if $\frac{y}{x}>1$; there are other cases too) of the fpp $n$ times, before reaching the top-right corner exactly and repeating. This means that $\frac{y}{x}$ is rational. On the torus corresponding to the fpp this means that the line wraps around the torus $n$ times if the point $z$ has order $n$. (See picture below.)

**Question:** If $z \in \mathbb{C}$, not purely imaginary, has infinite order, does this happen if and only if $\frac{y}{x}$ is irrational? Does the resulting line/curve on the fpp self-intersect? Does it eventually fill up the entire fpp? Or does it leave most of it empty? What about its image on the torus? Is this a space-filling curve? Or am I just being sloppy with my intuition here?

[image]

**Note:** This is based on section 2.7, "Torus as $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$" in *Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach* by Garrity et al.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The points on your line with slope $k$ are parametrized as  $P(t):=t+kti+\Lambda$, $t\in\Bbb{R}$. If we have $P(t_1)=P(t_2)$ for some $t_1\neq t_2$, then we get the pair of equations
$$
t_2=t_1+m,\qquad kt_2=kt_1+n
$$
for some integers $m,n$. Clearly $m\neq0$, so plugging the first equation into the
second yields $km=n$ and therefore $k=n/m$ is rational.

> If $k=y/x$ is irrational, then the curve does not intersect itself.

But

> The curve is not space-filling.

We see that for the $x$-coordinates in the above pair of equations to match we need $t_2\in t_1+\Bbb{Z}$. For a fixed $t_1$ this happens only for countably infinitely many choices of $t_2$. In other words, even when $k$ is irrational the line passes through only countably infinitely many points with a fixed $x$-coordinate. Also, the line only covers a set of measure zero, because it is a countable union of finite length line segments.

What your visual intuition is telling you is that when $k=y/x$ is irrational, the line will be dense on the torus. This is because for any $t_1$, the points $t_1+i k(t_1+m)+\Lambda$, with $m$ an arbitrary integer, are on the line. As $k$ is irrational, the image of the subgroup $k\Bbb{Z}$ is [dense](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html) on $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}$.
Actually if we assume a bit more we can even say the following. If the triple $\{1,x,y\}$ is linearly independent over $\Bbb{Q}$, then the set of points $n(x+iy)+\Lambda$ gotten with
an **integer**  parameter $n$ is already a dense subset of $\Bbb{C}/\Lambda$. This is an instance of the generalized [Kronecker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_theorem). On the elliptic curve this means that integer multiples of such a point form a dense set.

Comment: I like your  method of showing  it is not space-filling. Much easier  than mine :Consider the torus $T$ as a closed subspace of $R^3$.  For each $1\times 1$ closed square $S$ in $\mathbb C,$ with corners in $\Lambda,$  the equivalence class of the intersection of  the line with $S$ is a closed nowhere-dense subset of $T.$ And $T$ is a Baire space.

Comment: This is helpful, and makes sense too, because I can see why $k\mathbb{Z}$ would be dense but why it still wouldn't be space-filling, since the rationals are dense but have measure zero (since they are countable, as presumably $k\mathbb{Z}$ would also be). I really appreciate this answer.